# How to get object ID of a file at a specific commit?

Tags: git

If I want the contents of a file at a specific commit, I can use the command `git show [revision]:[filename]`, such as `git master:Jenkinsfile`.

Instead of the contents of the file, how do I get the object ID of a file at a specific commit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be through the plumbing [rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) command: e.g. `git rev-parse master:Jenkinsfile`